# Transferring files to a fast computer on the network and queuing the files for rendering

Tags: python, networking, render, maya, nuke

The task I want to accomplish is to send a copy of the opened file, transfer it to a location on the server, and for the fast render farm pc to open it, render the file, then close itself, essentially dumping all hardware intensive tasks onto one computer.

I also want to make sure that only one file is rendered/opened at a time.

What do I need to know to accomplish this ? How would you go about this ? It's about Maya Batch Rendering(.ma) as well as Nuke files (.nk)

Comment: I can't help thinking you'd fare better with `maya` and `nuke` tags rather than `networking`, `transfer` or `execute`. Is this Windows also?

Comment: how many machines do you want to limit access at a time? if you want to ensure a file is only opened by one client, you'll have to roll your own file system replacement which could get pretty hairy. Is the idea here that you have one machine that's beefy, and one thats weak, and you want to offload calculations to the beefy machine? I can't say I've ever heard of it done "live" as you want it.

Comment: There are many render farm managers out there some of them are free, some of them are free with a few machines. Sounds exactly what you need. Submit a file to the farm, let it calculate on a render/batch node and you are done.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using socket library(pre-installed) and the flask library. With them you can enstablish a connection between two or more pcs.
For Flask here is a site that can help you
[https://pythonbasics.org/flask-upload-file/#:~:text=It%20is%20very%20simple%20to,it%20to%20the%20required%20location](https://pythonbasics.org/flask-upload-file/#:%7E:text=It%20is%20very%20simple%20to,it%20to%20the%20required%20location).
For Socket here is another site
https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/send-receive-files-using-sockets-python
And I tou search on google or youtube you can find mano tutorial about it